# How to solve problems Mark and Toys question on Hackerrank

Tags: go

I have tried solving the question, but some test cases failed.

> The Question is: Mark and Jane are very happy after having their first
> child. Their son loves toys, so Mark wants to buy some. There are a
> number of different toys lying in front of him, tagged with their
> prices. Mark has only a certain amount to spend, and he wants to
> maximize the number of toys he buys with this money. Given a list of
> toy prices and an amount to spend, determine the maximum number of
> gifts he can buy.
>
> Note Each toy can be purchased only once. Example prices = [1,2,3,4] k
> = 7
>
> The budget is 7 units of currency. He can buy items that cost [1, 2,
> 3] for 6, or [3, 4] for 7 units. The maximum is 3 items.
>
> Function Description
>
> Complete the function maximumToys in the editor below.
>
> maximumToys has the following parameter(s):
>
> - int prices[n]: the toy prices
> - int k: Mark's budget
>
> Returns
>
> - int: the maximum number of toys
>
> The first line contains two integers, n and k, the number of priced
> toys and the amount Mark has to spend. The next line contains n
> space-separated integers prices[i]
>
> sample input:  7 50 1 12 5 111 200 1000 10
>
> sample output: 4

```
This is my answer:

func maximumToys(prices []int32, k int32) int32 {
    // Write your code here

   // Sorting the prices
   for i := 0; i < len(prices); i++ {
        for j := i + 1; j < len(prices); j++ {
            // Swap the number
            if prices[i] > prices[j] {
                temp := prices[i]
                prices[i] = prices[j]
                prices[j] = temp
            }
        }
    }
    
    for l := 0; l < len(prices); l++ {
        k -= int32(prices[l])
        if k < prices[l] {
            return int32(l)
        } 
    }
    
    lengthPrices := len(prices)
    
    return int32(lengthPrices)
}
```

***I have tried sorting the array of numbers and then variable k reduce with each number in the array. In the end, I return the length of array prices***

[enter link description here question Mark and Toys](https://www.hackerrank.com/challenges/mark-and-toys/copy-from/234817830?h_l=interview&playlist_slugs%5B%5D=interview-preparation-kit&playlist_slugs%5B%5D=sorting)

Comment: Instead of sorting the prices, you should compute the number of toys you can buy with a selected subset of the `prices` array, and find out all subsets.

Comment: The code is essentially right (and you're using the right algorithm). However the body of the `l` loop is wrong. It should be something like `if k < prices[l] { return int32(l - 1) } ; k -= prices[l]`.

Comment: (Commenters above have misread the problem - you can't use a greedy algorithm if you have to spend as much money as possible (the "knapsack" problem), but maximizing the number of items bought can be solved by greedily buying the cheapest items first).

Answer (score 0):

It feels like the simplest strategy to just to buy the cheapest toys:

```golang
package main

import (
    "log"
    "sort"
)

func maximumToys(prices []int32, k int32) int32 {
    sort.Slice(prices, func(a, b int) bool {
        return prices[a] < prices[b]
    })
    sum := int32(0)
    for i := 0; i < len(prices); i++ {
        sum += prices[i]
        if sum > k {
            return int32(i)
        }
    }
    return int32(len(prices))
}

func main() {
    tests := []struct {
        prices      []int32
        money, want int32
    }{
        {[]int32{1, 2, 3, 4}, 7, 3},
        {[]int32{1, 12, 5, 111, 200, 1000, 10}, 50, 4},
    }

    for i, t := range tests {
        n := maximumToys(t.prices, t.money)
        log.Print("test ", i, " result: got=", n, " wanted=", t.want, " passed=", n == t.want)
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
import (
....
    "sort"
)


func maximumToys(prices []int32, k int32) int32 {
    // Write your code here
    
    sort.Slice(prices, func(i, j int) bool {
        return prices[i] < prices[j]
    })

    var sum float64 = 0
    var count int32 = 0
    for _, v := range prices {
        sum = sum + float64(v)
        if sum <= float64(k) {
            count++
        }
    }
    
    return count
}
```

or this one is you want to break the loop once you reach the limit

```
func maximumToys(prices []int32, k int32) int32 {
    // Write your code here
    
    sort.Slice(prices, func(i, j int) bool {
        return prices[i] < prices[j]
    })

    var sum float64 = 0
    var count int32 = 0
    for _, v := range prices {
        sum = sum + float64(v)
        if sum > float64(k) {
            break
        }
        count++
    }
    
    return count
}
```